# Picture dimension reduction

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I need to reduce my picture dimension by means of *singular value decomposition*.

I've seen a lot of sources for this theme. They advise to use the following:

```python
m, n = img.shape
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(img)
#U.shape = m * m; S.shape = m * n; V.shape = n * n
img_cut = U[:, :x] @ np.diag(S[:x, :x]) @ V[:x, :]
```

This is supposed to reduce the size of the image down to `x`. But the size of the image will be the same `m * n`, because `U.shape[0]` and `V.shape[1]` are remained the same. What can I do?

Comment: I am interested to understand what you are trying to do exactly. I take you are not just trying to reduce resolution (in which case, that is not at all what people have in mind when they talk about "dimension reduction").

Comment: It is important to understand what SVD (or PCA) does: it finds redundancies (or quasi-redundancies) in a bunch of vectors, and take advantage of that to represent them with less data (in a subspace smaller than the space of all vectors). So if you have vectors `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, `0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1` and `1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9`, it takes advantage of the fact that the 3rd is the sum of the two first, to allows you to "code" the 3 vectors with the only information of the two first, and of a way to build the 3rd (here a vector `[1,1]`) from them.

Comment: It is not exactly how things are done in SVD. But at its core, it is what it relies on: the fact that the rank of the matrix made of all the vectors is smaller than `n`, or at least that a very similar matrix exists with a smaller rank, that is that it exists some linear combination of columns that are 0 (or almost so).

Comment: So, all that to say: what you are relying on here, when using SVD to reduce the dimension of a matrix (see @Daraan's answer about how this is a reduction), is redundancies on the columns (or lines, that goes together) of the matrix. I am really not sure that can be applied very well on a matrix that is made of the pixels of an image. People usually don't think of an image as a bunch of rows that are quite similar. Potential repeating patterns are not really in rows.

Comment: One more realistic usage of SVD to reduce dimension, could be, for example, to reduce dimension of colorspace. You have a m×n×3 color image. You flatten it as a (mn)×3 2D array. And then, use SVD to try to find a more compact colorspace (it would work beautifully if your image is, in reality, a black&white, or sepia, image, encoded in RGB). Or if you have an hyperspectral image, and want to reduce it, as, after all, human visual cortex does.

Comment: Another more realistic example, would be if you had a bunch of k m×n images. And wanted to benefit from redundancies among them. You flatten that to have a k×(mn) matrix representing your k images. And then, perform a SVD, so that you can save only x (with x<k) "images" (with quotes, because they won't look as real images. But it is x bunch of mn numbers). And more realisticly (since people don't use SVD just for data compression) do some AI/data science on the reduction, rather than on the whole thing).

Comment: So understand that SVD works on vectors, not 2D-arrays. The matrix on which you perform a SVD must be seen (as, after all, all matrix we use in linear algebra, but unlike, usally, images, that are 2D-arrays, but not really matrix, from an interpretation point of view), so the matrix must be seen as a bunch of columns (or of rows, depending on how to choose to interpret. But not as a bunch of 2d areas). So ask yourself: is the "atom" of whatever processing I want to do in fine is a "column" of an image?

Comment: As both a linear algebra teacher, and a researcher in computer vision, I must say, I have hard time imagining a case where it makes sense. You are not the only one to do so. For example [this post](https://medium.com/balabit-unsupervised/image-compression-using-singular-value-decomposition-de20451c69a3) does exactly that. They even start to separate the 3 channels, when they should, on the contrary, keep them together (since that the only dimensions along which it makes some sense). Getting result like [this](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:640/format:webp/0*vqHw6d3HnuNhXFDB.png)

Comment: See how the defects in this image tend to spread along rows and columns, and not, as you would see in heavily reduced jpg, in patterns and blocs? That is because that is what SVD does: find redundancies in rows and columns. And express rows and columns as linear combination of a reduced set of rows and columns.

Comment: All this rant to say: it would help if we knew what you are really trying to do (for what end, in which context). Because I suspect SVD isn't really what you want, or at least not on just the m×n matrix made directly of the m×n rows and columns of an image.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I've read all the materals. With regard to the PIL library it may reduce the volume of images, but not to the Scikit-learn library (data science), where you input a matrix of the image. Where the complexity of the calculations depends on sizes of the matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same sizes as it was. SVD didn't help me to reduce 256 * 256 a matrix for the image down to lower sizes with approximate closeliness according to the left principal components.

Comment: The fact is that I have above 9000 images (256 * 256) and I need to cluster them. According I have a matrix for input 9000 * 65536, which is too much and can not be calculated even on the Google Colab (virtual machine).

Comment: I supposed, that I could symmetrically reduce the sizes of the image view matrix, since I can reduce its columns or rows (for example through the PCA method), multiplying a singular values matrix by a right (may be left for the rows) singular vectors matrix.

Answer (score 1):

As you have realized the dimension is the same.
The principal of SVD is that you decompose a matrix into three parts `M=USV^T`.
By using only the first *x* singular vectors and values you can reduce a data point to `x` dimensions.

For this you only use two of the matrices:

```
img_cut = U[:, :x] @ np.diag(S[:x, :x])
```

You can likewise do it with V which is a reduction.
When thinking about tabular data, doing it this was is not a reduction in features but in samples.

---

By using the other matrix you can reconstruct your original data - with some error depending on *x*. This reconstructed data is a *low rank approximation* with rank *x*.

```
img_reconstructed = img_cut @ V[:x, :]
```

Comment: But if I have an image with sizes 256 * 256, for example. Where columns and rows have the same sense. And if I do so:

    img_cut = U[:, :x] @ np.diag(S[:x, :x])

then I have reduced comuns only. But I want to remain 4 principal components and have matrix 4 * 4. I must to reduce both dimensions: rows and columns. Can I do something like this? (I realize, that it's hardly ever right)

    imc_cut = U[:4, :4] @ S[:4, :4] @ V[:4, :4]

Comment: Well you can do  `U[:x, :x] @ np.diag(S[:x, :x]) @ V[:x,:x]` to get a square matrix, like you said. but that is not a use-case of the SVD as far as I know. You have to try if it is useful for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The SVD decomposition of a matrix *A* does not change the dimensions of *A*. And it wouldn't be a valuable thing to just reduce and image size, for, it would reduce the image **quality**. But we want to preserve image quality!

Instead, the SVD decomposition *A = U Σ V^T* means that we keep the same dimension for *A*, but we can replace three matrices *U*, *Σ*, *V* by much **smaller** matrices *U_r*, *\Sigma_r*, *V_r* which require much less numbers to write, but the product *A_r = U_r Σ_r V_r^T* of which is very close to our original matrix *A*.

These lecture notes explain the thing in detail:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318066716_Linear_Algebra_Theory_and_Algorithms?o=Linear_Algebra

In particular, please see **Section 38.2** and **Section 41.1** (this section deals with images exactly!).